Show that the ring of germs at 0 is local
I have been posed the following problem:

Prove that $C_0$ (which is the ring of germs of continuous functions at $0$) is a local ring, with maximal ideal $M$ consisting of
the germs of functions that vanish at 0.

I have shown that $M$ is maximal in $C_0$, however to prove locality I have:
Let $P$ be an ideal in $C_0$ such that it is not $M$ and there exists a surjective homomorphism $\phi: C_0 \to ℝ$ given by $\phi([f]) = f(0)$. Then, $P$ is maximal in $C_0$ iff $C_0/P$ is isomorphic to ℝ. We see that ℝ is isomorphic to $C_0/P$ only if $\ker(\phi) = P$. Since $\ker(\phi)$ is precisely $M$, $P$ must be $M$. Therefore, the only maximal ideal in $C_0$ is $M$ and $C_0$ is a local ring.
My mentor says my solution is incorrect since I did not use the definition of $C_0$ as a ring of germs, could anyone please clarify what is meant by this?


Then, $P$ is maximal in $C_0$ iff $C_0/P$ is isomorphic to ℝ.

This does not follow. If $P$ is maximal you only know that $C_0/P$ is a field, but a priori it could be a nontrivial field extension of $\mathbb{R}$. There are situations similar to this situation where we get such extensions, for example nontrivial ultrapowers of $\mathbb{R}$.

We see that ℝ is isomorphic to $C_0/P$ only if $\ker(\phi) = P$.

This does not follow and is the most important mistake. $C_0/P$ could just be a different quotient which is also isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ with a different kernel.

My mentor says my solution is incorrect since I did not use the definition of $C_0$ as a ring of germs, could anyone please clarify what is meant by this?

In fact you used almost nothing about $C_0$ at all so this argument couldn't possibly have been correct. All you used was the existence of the evaluation homomorphism $\phi : C_0 \to \mathbb{R}$ and nothing else and of course this is not enough information to conclude, e.g. it does not distinguish $C_0$ from the full ring of continuous functions.
Anyway, here's a big hint:

 Show that every element of $C_0$ not in $M$ is invertible. You will actually need to use the definition of a germ to do this.

